# How do I sanitize GitHub user names & repositories?

Tags: python, github, github-api

I am writing an Python-based IRC bot plugin that takes in a GitHub owner and repository name, then makes some GitHub API calls based on those. I need to make sure that neither input is malicious. Presumably a regular expression would work, but I can't find documentation on which characters are acceptable. I'll be dealing with strings that were already decoded as utf8.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find anything explicitly stating the allowed characters for repository and user names.  But I think maybe the best answer is to just not sweat it too much.  Don't worry about if it's "malicious"--if GitHub isn't handling that on their end that's their problem.

What you can do is this:  According to [the API docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/#client-errors) an invalid field posted to the API should result in an HTTP 422 error (I've gotten these myself when I've had bugs in code using their API).  The body of the reponse contains a JSON object explaining the nature of the validation error.

So you can just let the API handle validation for you, and if you get one of those responses tell the user that their name is invalid.